# How can I cloud-host a website that only 3 or so people will use, or how to protect it from DDoS attacks?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I want to create a website with Django (I already know how to do that), but I want to host it on AWS (I can figure that out later), for I don't want my laptop to store the database. The problem is that I don't want anyone to be able to access it. I only wish for me and other 2 or 3 people to be able to see it.

If this is not possible, I could make a simple login page and create the users myself. That way, only the people I want will be able to use the web app. But this would leave it open to DDoS and many different types of attacks I don't know how to defend/prevent. So, now the question would be, do you guys know any tutorial on protecting your website from these attacks? I have looked online on these tutorials, but I only find how to defend from PS4 or WordPress. I am not looking for anything too big, as I said, I think that I could use `@login_required` from Django, and the only thing I will have to defend is the login page.

I am almost sure 1 of these two options can be done. However, if they can't be done, I don't want to waste my time creating the web app and risk losing a lot of money from these attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how much you really want to spend on DDoS protection. Nevertheless, the best source of information about DDoS on AWS is AWS whitepaper titled [AWS Best Practices for DDoS Resiliency](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf). It provides a lot of useful information about DDoS and which AWS services you can use to protect your applications.

A common and probably the cheapest and easiest to setup way of protecting against DDoS is putting your application behind **CloudFront**. From the white paper:

> Amazon CloudFront only accepts well-formed connections, which **helps prevent many common DDoS attacks**, like SYN floods and UDP reflection attacks, from reaching your origin.

CloudFront uses AWS Shield Standard  (free) to help protect against DDoS. But, if protection against DDoS if of uttermost importance to you, then you can get AWS Shield Advances (not free - very expensive).

There are other ways which depend on your budget and application architecture. In the AWS whitepaper you will find information about different ways of protection against DDoS on AWS.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful information. I thought that the protection had to be set up from your code, but now I know it doesn't. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joaquin No problem. Glad could help.